# Methods in Components in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The following code gives me some next error.
All I'm trying to do is input data, then the button should do an alert and output the data that's inputted.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1> {{ greeting }} </h1>
    <label for="value"> Name </label>
    <input type="text" v-model="value" placeholder="input name">
    <button type="submit" v-on:click="clickHandler" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="./main.js"></script>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'input-data',
  data: function() {
    return {
      value: String,
      greeting: "Welcome to Heaven Stranger"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickHandler: function() {
      alert("Name of SIR: " + value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want to acces component data dont forget to this dot "`this.`"

Answer (score 0):

```
methods: {
    clickHandler: function() {
      alert("Name of SIR: " + this.value);
    }
  }
```

here your code to [sandbox and play](https://codesandbox.io/s/38m7mqk46m)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22486874)

Comment: added relevant part